# Android HttpsURLConnection is very slow to return 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpsurlconnection

Update: They've changed the site. Instead of giving a generic 502 error from nginx it now gives an instant 403 with a custom message. This makes it impossible to reproduce the issue.

I have an app that gets data from Weather.gov. They're having an outage and I've discovered that HttpsURLConnection takes minutes to return the status.

```
String urlString = "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/VEF/127,91/forecast";
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL (urlString).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
connection.setReadTimeout (1000);
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode (); // This doesn't return for a minute or three
```

- If I open the link in my browser, it returns instantly.
- If I do this   as a desktop program, it also returns instantly.
- As stated, it takes minutes to return in the Android Studio Emulator.
- Adjusting the timeout makes no difference.

The question then is: How do I get the response back faster so that I can inform the user that there is a problem. It is, of course, in a thread so I can display a "Working" status, but I shouldn't need to. As stated, other systems come back with the status instantly.

Note: Someone is probably dying to tell me to use a different weather source. That would be missing the point. Connection issues happen all the time, I want the app to be better about them.

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973, built on August 17, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

My desktop JDK is:
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
```

Comment: Have you tried a more modern HTTP client, such as OkHttp?

Comment: Why are you setting a user agent?

Comment: You should open an input stream and read.

Comment: You should use a real device. Not an emulator.

Comment: `If I open the link in my browser,` A browser on the emulator? On your Android device?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have not attempted to rewrite to a different client. It really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @blackapps, I don't recall why I put a user agent in there. Possibly copy/paste. Rather irrelevant though.

Comment: @blackapps, even if it worked perfectly on a real device and the issue was only in the emulator, the emulator is far to handy for development to give up on. But it's in both so there you go.

Comment: I suggested OkHttp because, in addition to being actively maintained and the preferred HTTP client among Android app developers, it works for your circumstance. I get the 502 response in a second or so.

Comment: @CommonsWare, OK. I'll look into the difficulty of changing over and the resulting change in my app size. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Well after seeing CommonsWare using OkHttp with nice result i would contribute that that url gives an IOException within a second (on a real device) using HttpUrlConnection.

But i open an input stream and try to read. Not looking at a resultcode at all...

Why would one look at a resultcode if one would grab the page content..

Comment: I really thought I had said, but I didn't. The real code did open the stream and was the initial exhibit of the problem. The result code check was put in while trying to get the problem fixed. I decided that it made the example simpler so I wrote up the question that way.

Comment: Also upon reflection, since the result code comes in as the first line of the headers, it could be available long before the input stream to the body could return. Depending on its value, the overhead of reading the body can be avoided. Given that, I'd suggest that checking the result code before opening the input stream is probably always the better code.

Comment: Well if you think that waiting minutes is better than a second, please go on.

Comment: I don't understand. On my real device, using HttpsUrlConnection takes minutes for either getting the Input Stream or for getting the Response Status. Obviously, if getting the stream took a second, and the code minutes, I wouldn't ask for the status for practical reasons.