# Fluttter android (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) write to Downloads folder

Tags: android, flutter, oserror

I'm trying to copy a file that's in the device's temporary folder to the `Downloads` folder, but I'm getting this error in the `file.copy` function:

```
PathAccessException: Cannot copy file to '/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf', path = '/data/user/0/myapp/cache/file-pdf.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Here is the code:

```
await Permission.storage.request();
Directory downloadFolder = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download/")
String pdfName = "test";
await file.copy("${downloadFolder.path}$pdfName.pdf");
```

I'm using `permission_handler: ^11.1.0`, and I wrote this to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is my `build.gradle` configuration:

```
android {
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    }
}
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.18.0-0.2.pre, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale pt-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I need this code to run in **Android 10 to 13.**

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: That READ and WRITE permission are only usable for Android 12- devices. So you have to make some adaptations if you want to be ready for 10 to 13. And there is already 14.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714446/android-httpsurlconnection-is-very-slow-to-return-502-bad-gateway/77717753?noredirect=1#comment137015023_77717753

Comment: The device is Android 10. Can you specify some references to make the adaptions to others Android versions?

Comment: Does it already work on Android Q/10,? Can you read and write external storage?

Comment: No, the OS error 13 happens on Android 10

Comment: For an Android 10 device you should also  request legacy external storage in application tag of manifest file.

Comment: Adding the tag worked for Android 10, thanks! What about the others versions?

Comment: Well you can read that between the lines... Only request those read and write permissions at runtume for Android 10, 11, 12 devices. Then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Saving files in the Downloads folder worked (on Android 10 to 13) when I added the tag below to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Thanks to @blackapps for help.